# AngularJS listenForEmail is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with Angularjs in a small extension. This is how I'm defining a function inside a service scope

```
$scope.listenForEmail = function(){
    try{
        var emailObject = appAPI.db.get('emailObject'); 
        console.log(emailObject);
        return emailObject;
    }catch(e){
        setTimeout($scope.listenForEmail(),5000);
    }

};
```

and then right below I call it as so

```
 //email object
    var emailObject = $scope.listenForEmail();
```

But I keep getting the error 
`TypeError: $scope.listenForEmail is not a function at new eval`

I'd deeply appreciate any help on why this is happening.

Comment: plz post the complete controller and the HTML as well

Comment: im trying to call the function from within the controller. is that perhaps the reason its giving me this error?

Comment: @Irtza.QC you might be trying to call it before it is defined? i.e make the call after `$scope.listenForEmail = function(){`. Also timeout takes function ref so you might want to do `setTimeout($scope.listenForEmail,5000);` removing `()`. Inorder for digest cycle to run you might want to use $timeout instead of setTimeout

Comment: Any other JavaScript errors before this?

Comment: @PSL no. the controller is defined lines 109-118. the call is on line 120. 
 no other errors before this

Comment: You should make use of `$timeout` to correctly hook into angular's digest cycle. Also if `appAPI.db.get` is async and returns a promise im not certain this will work as expected.

Comment: @Irtza.QC Please replicate the issue in a demo

Comment: $timeout fixed it. thank you so much!

Comment: if you add that comment as an answer I will happily select it as the answer @PSL

Comment: @Irtza.QC glad it helped. Knew using plain `setTimeout` causes issues. didn't expect it to cause an issue like this however.

Comment: @Irtza.QC But i am still confused on how `$timeout` can be related to `$scope.listenForEmail is not a function at new eval`. `$timeout` v/s `setTimeout` is a silent issue, it wont throw any error. Which line was throwing that error as per console?.

Comment: its a chrome extension im building, so it doesnt give line numbers, but the error was always the same, `$scope.listenForEmail is not a function at new eval`

Comment: I'm trying to debug exactly why `$timeout` has fixed it. I'm a little perplexed and intrigued by it, i meant the comment more of a heads up. Didn't expect to actually be the issue.

Comment: Sorry im stumped. Couldn't replicate your issue. Only think i can think of is some strange promise madness.  Does `appAPI.db.get` return a promise? `$timeout` does so if `appAPI.db.get` does too and your using that returned promise in your controller it would complete the promise chain in a roundabout way and glue everything together. `setTimeout` doesn't return a promise so it could have broken something internally in angular in part of that promise chain. Besides that (which is just speculation) im lost.

Comment: `appAPI.db.get` gets a globally stored object. until its set by an external function, it stays undefined/null and on that error i call the function again, but when i get it i log the object returned.